# Bidi algorithm: correct rendering of HTML tags and Arabic text

Tags: javascript, unicode, bidi

I have the following text:

```
<a> النص $var </a>
```

When this text is displayed in a textarea with **RTL** direction it looks like this (screenshot):

[image]

I am trying to use Unicode control characters (LRM, RLM, LRI, RLI, PDF) to change direction of parts of this text.

I tried:

1. `\u200e<a>\u200f لنص \u200e $var </a>\u202c -(LRM<a>RLM لنص LRM$var </a>PDF)`

Result (screenshot):

[image]

2. `\u2066<a>\u202c\u2067 النص \u202c\u2066 $var </a>\u202c - (LRI<a>PDF RLI النص PDF LRI $var </a>PDF)`

Result (screenshot):

[image]

As can be seen, it not works. how to use Unicode control characters properly in this case?

Comment: I don't know if its required to keep the direction of the textarea as `RTL` , you can make it `LTR` and put another style which is : `text-align:right`.

`<textarea style='width:100%;direction:ltr;text-align:right'><a> النص $var </a></textarea>`

Comment: @Ashraf It is required because tags are inside Arabic text which must be in RTL textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bidi isolates are popped with PDI and not PDF. That’s why your attempts turned out wrong. Bracket the entire string with LRI (U+2066) and PDI (U+2069): `\u2066<a> النص $var </a>\u2069`